# SQL Serve Queue How to call and how to decide when it runs

Tags: sql, sql-server, queue, service-broker

I am new to a company that has SQL Server Queue in Broker (I have never used queues before)
this queue runs after hours (around 6 PM)

I want to know how can I force the queue to run/execute and how to change the specified time for it to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue is normally activated by something. Try scripting the queue from SSMS to see if there is an activation stored procedure, if so review/post the code.
Alternatively if there is nothing then you probably have a job or application that that is running a RECIEVE command against the queue.
You need to find this first.